# postToWall on facebook After login in iphone

Tags: iphone

Does anybody have idea about how to post a wall on 
  facebook after login button in iphone.
 i have to post default image and text.
     If yes in which fb class it have to write .i have latest sdk for facebook.
     Thanks

Comment: You can try the following link: http://www.raywenderlich.com/77/how-to-post-on-facebook-with-your-iphone-app http://www.raywenderlich.com/1626/how-to-post-to-a-users-wall-upload-photos-and-add-a-like-button-from-your-iphone-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using FBConnect library after login you can use the following method to post on the users wall

```
Facebook *facebook = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] facebook];
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"###yourAPIKeY###", @"api_key",
                                   @"###Your Message###", @"message",
                                   @"###link if you want###", @"link",
                                   @"### a picture if you want###", @"picture",
                                   @"###name of your fb app###", @"name",
                                   @"###Description###", @"description",
                                   nil];
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" 
                         andParams:params
                     andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                       andDelegate:self];
```

If you want it to happen right after the user logged in it should be implemented in the following method:

```
-(void) fbDidLogin
{
}
```

be sure to note that you need to ask from the user `publish_stream` permissions

Comment: Thanks for your help.i do the code same as u say in -(void) fbDidLogin method,but it crashes with bad access error.

Comment: What error does it return ? be sure to look at this line : `Facebook *facebook = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] facebook];` and make sure it's right for your code.

Comment: Also you should change the keys in the dictionary according to your needs and your api key