# Sharing text data on facebook ang twitter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, sharekit

I am working on an iphone quiz application. Now i need to share quiz result on facebook and twitter. I am wondering what to use. I've tried using **sharekit** but wasn't able to. Please give me step by step process of sharing data. Any other options would be highly appreciated. Please provide me with as many options as possible. Any one?

Answer (score 0):

You can post to facebook using FBConnect

I posted a code in the following answer:

[postToWall on facebook After login in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792120/posttowall-on-facebook-after-login-in-iphone/7792257#7792257)

Answer (score 0):

The original [ShareKit](http://www.getsharekit.com) is obsolete. You can try [ShareKit 2.0](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/). Make sure that you carefully follow [install wiki](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit).